# drop lowest n each time period

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, dataset, purrr

I have a problem where I have repeated samples of a population, and want to remove individuals with the lowest N values of a sampled measure from a candidate pool.

For a more tangible example, imagine a competition where each week all teams receive a score from playing a game, and each week the lowest-performing two teams are eliminated.

For the example dataset below, we should have 10 teams remaining after Week 1, 8 after Week 2, 6 after Week 3, and 4 after Week 4.

Reprex below currently produces the correct `df_result` for Week 1, but not for subsequent weeks. Appreciate any recommendations you can offer.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

set.seed(42)

df <- tibble::tibble(
  week = rep(1:4, 12) %>% sort(),
  team = rep(stringr::str_c("team_", 1:12), 4),
  score = runif(48, 0, 100) %>% ceiling()
) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(score) %>%
  # dplyr::group_by(week) %>%
  split(.$week) 

df_result <- df %>% 
  purrr::map2(
    .x = ., .y = dplyr::lag(.),
    ~ dplyr::filter(.data = .x, !(team %in% .y$team)) %>% dplyr::slice_max(
      .data = .,
      order_by = score,
      n = -2,
      with_ties = TRUE
    ))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: you could also use `reduce()` if you only wanted the final result

Comment: M.Wood I appreciate you trying to do edits if I got something wrong or if you want to make it tidier but your edits to my answer broke the code, so I had to roll them back. I hope you can understand!

Comment: hi @Mark , sorry about that... I think I broke something on my side when I copied code over and updated some of the variable names to the 'real' dataset. Now that I know there's an edit history on a question I can traverse, I'll know to roll back what end up being spurious changes in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [accumulate](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/accumulate.html):

```
df |> 
  accumulate(\(x, d) {
    d |>
      filter(team %in% x$team) |>
      slice_max(order_by = score, n = -2)}, .init = df$`1`) |> 
      # accumulate (frustratingly!) keeps the initial value in the results, so we need to remove it
    tail(-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in base R using subsetting via a `for` loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(df)){
  df[[i]] <- df[[i]][order(df[[i]]$score, decreasing = TRUE),] 
  if(i == 1) df[[i]] <- df[[i]][-((nrow(df[[i]])-1):nrow(df[[i]])),]
  else{
    df[[i]] <- df[[i]][df[[i]]$team %in% df[[i-1]]$team,]
    df[[i]] <- df[[i]][-((nrow(df[[i]])-1):nrow(df[[i]])),]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$`1`
# A tibble: 10 × 3
    week team    score
   <int> <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1 team_1     98
 2     1 team_6     79
 3     1 team_8     75
 4     1 team_9     68
 5     1 team_2     62
 6     1 team_12    52
 7     1 team_5     40
 8     1 team_4     35
 9     1 team_3     34
10     1 team_11    27

$`2`
# A tibble: 8 × 3
   week team   score
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>
1     2 team_2    99
2     2 team_5    85
3     2 team_8    83
4     2 team_3    76
5     2 team_9    70
6     2 team_1    68
7     2 team_4    57
8     2 team_6    19

$`3`
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   week team   score
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>
1     3 team_4    72
2     3 team_9    59
3     3 team_2    48
4     3 team_6    38
5     3 team_1    22
6     3 team_3    20

$`4`
# A tibble: 4 × 3
   week team   score
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>
1     4 team_1    78
2     4 team_2    57
3     4 team_6    31
4     4 team_3    24
```